# Not able to click button using selenium Python webdriver

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button on a website using Selenium Webdriver python and I see the button getting highlighted, but not getting clicked using `click()` function.

Below is the html code for the button I am trying to click

```
a id="btn_Reset" class="top_btn" onclick="Reset();" href="#">Reboot< /a
```

I am trying to click on the button using id

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("btn_Reset").click()
```

I also tried xpath with same result

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a").click()
```

Comment: This may not solve your problem but, please try using relative xpath instead of absolute xpath

Comment: `.click()` has no return. What is the assignment to `inputElement` for?

Comment: could you provide `HTML` for parent element also?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a silly matter of doing it this way:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("btn_Reset")

inputElement.click()
```